# Problem with Django app unit tests under Visual Studio Code

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-models, visual-studio-code

I have a draft of the Django project with the added one application (e.g. my_app). In this app I have places tests.py file with one test:

```
import unittest

class Test_MyModel(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_dummy(self):
    self.assertEqual(1,1)
```

In this case, this dummy test is discoverd by Visual Studio Code and could be executed in it, also it's possible to launch this test from command line:

```
python manage.py test
```

When I modify my file with unit test add import some model (placed in file models.py) from my_app:

```
import unittest

from .models import MyModel # new added line

class Test_MyModel(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_dummy(self):
    self.assertEqual(1,1)
```

In this case I'm still be able run test from command line without any problems, but VSC doesn't discover my test and in the Python Test Log in the VSC I get error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: tests (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: tests
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 434, in _find_test_path
module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 375, in _get_module_from_name
__import__(name)
File "/Users/myuser/Projects/backend/my_app/tests.py", line 3, in <module>
from my_app.models import MyModel
File "/Users/myuser/Projects/backend/my_app/models.py", line 4, in <module>
class MyModel(models.Model):
File "/Users/myuser/Projects/virtualenvs/my_app_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 103, in __new__
app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
File "/Users/myuser/Projects/virtualenvs/my_app_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 252, in get_containing_app_config
self.check_apps_ready()
File "/Users/myuser/Projects/virtualenvs/my_app_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 134, in check_apps_ready
settings.INSTALLED_APPS
File "/Users/myuser/Projects/virtualenvs/my_app_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File "/Users/myuser/Projects/virtualenvs/my_app_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 64, in _setup
% (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Any hints or advice how can I resolve this problem and start fully using unit test under VSC for models test?

Answer (score 4):

I've found a solution to my problem. I need to add below lines into my init.py file in my_app folder.

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_app_project.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: This solution also resolved my issues: (1) Django unit tests weren't discoverable in Visual Studio Code; or (2) I got a "TypeError: argument of type 'ConnectionHandler' is not iterable" message if they were discoverable.